# Clear HTML Canvas when new chart is displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas

So I am building an AngularJs chart that utilizes an Angular Library to create the chart on a Canvas tag. However when I drag and drop a new data set onto the canvas to redraw it continues to hold the old data. What I am trying to accomplish is If (there is new data){ clear the canvas}. I know I have to use:

```
canvasReset.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

somewhere but what I am really looking for is an event handler to use to assist me in determining if anything is on the canvas, and if so clearing it. However, I am not looking for mouseover mouse-click,etc. But something that is just generally looking to see if the canvas is being utilized.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, you can't. But you can catch mouseevnets, or you can wrap canvas ctx drawing functions,like

```
var fill = ctx.fill;
ctx.fill = function(){
    fill.apply(this, arguments);
    setDirty();
};
```

Comment: why not something like this:

Comment: canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        document.getElementById("base").addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
            if (canvas.toDataURL() == document.getElementById('blank').toDataURL())
                canvasReset.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        });

Comment: because your solution is expensive for performance. For small canvas like 100x100  it can be work, but 1000x1000 you can have performance issues. toDataUrl() is converting bitmap to base64 string, and I tested your solution with comparing of each pixel and results are, 38ms for your solution and 44 for pixel comparing. so your solution is slow.